# Where does System Preferences store the name of the Time Machine Destination

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, time-machine, system-settings

I am trying to create a script to determine the destination of time machine on a number of computers I manage. It shows very clearly via Time Machine Settings in System Prefs. I need to be able to find that info via command line.

Answer (score 4):

The tmutil utility does exactly that, but I think it was only added in Lion.

As an added bonus, Apple doesn't document the tmutil argument you'll need, but I dug through the output of "strings /usr/bin/tmutil" and found this, which is what you're looking for:

> tmutil destinationinfo

Also, "tmutil status" will tell you if a backup is currently running. It's another undocumented command.

Answer (score 0):

In this link you can find the answer: https://superuser.com/questions/20887/in-what-preference-file-does-time-machine-store-the-backup-volume-name

`/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`